# MPI send derived data type with pointer in Fortran 90

Tags: mpi, fortran90

I would like to send a user defined data type as:

```
TYPE CELL
    INTEGER :: NUM
    TYPE(CELL), POINTER :: NEXT => NULL()
END TYPE CELL

TYPE CELLLIST
    INTEGER :: NBCELL
    TYPE(CELL), POINTER :: BEGIN => NULL()
END TYPE CELLLIST
```

and the variable to be sent by MPI is defined as:

```
TYPE(CELLLIST) :: _CELLLIST
```

In this variable, _CELLIST%NBCELL denotes the length of the list, and a pointer of type CELL points to the head of the list.

I'd like to use MPI_send and MPI_recv to transfer the cell list via MPI. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending pointers from one MPI process to another is pointless.

The problem is that they, pointers, are process-specific.  It's a reasonable analogy to think of a pointer as storing the memory address of its target. That memory address isn't portable, there is no concept of an address in one process's address space being the same as an address in another process's address space.

You will have to unravel the chain of pointers in your `_CELLLIST`, send across the `CELLS`, then rebuild the pointer chain on the target process(es).

I suppose that you might pack the `CELLS` into an array for transfer.  Or you might send one `CELL` at a time on the understanding that the receiving process(es) will rebuild the dynamic data structure in the order in which it receives the messages containing the `CELL`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will create an array to explore the celllist and send the array instead of the user type variable _celllist.

Comment: Yes, the pointer information becomes useless. No to packing or one-at-a-time sending: check in to the `MPI_Type_hindexed` instead, which is like the indexed type, but based on absolute addresses.