# Problem in passing own datatype with pointers

Tags: c++, mpi

There was a problem with passing pointer of object of class via `MPI_Send(...)`. I want to pass a pointer to an object from one node to another. When I try to send `PhysObject` I got this message in receive thread

> Prog.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. Exit code 0xc0000005.

I understand that problem with memory, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

Here is the code of my classes

```cpp
class Vector3 final
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
//...(methods)
}
class MyObject final
{
public:
    Vector3 Force;
    Vector3 Speed;
//...(methods)
};
class PhysObject final
{
public:
    MyObject* obj_;
//...(methods)
};
```

Here is a code of datatype init

```cpp
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Datatype dataTypeVec3;
int          lenVec3[3] = { 1, 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint     posVec3[3] = { offsetof(class Vector3, x),offsetof(class Vector3, y), offsetof(class Vector3, z) };
MPI_Datatype typVec3[3] = { MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE };
MPI_Type_create_struct(3, lenVec3, posVec3, typVec3, &dataTypeVec3);
MPI_Type_commit(&dataTypeVec3);
MPI_Datatype dataTypeMyObject;
int          lenMyObject[2] = { 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint     posMyObject[2] = { offsetof(class MyObject, Force),offsetof(class MyObject, Speed)};
MPI_Datatype typMyObject[2] = { dataTypeVec3, dataTypeVec3};
MPI_Type_create_struct(2, lenMyObject, posMyObject, typMyObject, &dataTypeMyObject);
MPI_Type_commit(&dataTypeMyObject);
MPI_Datatype dataTypePhysObject;
int          lenPhysObject[1] = { 1};
MPI_Aint     posPhysObject[1] = { offsetof(class PhysObject, obj_) };
MPI_Datatype typPhysObject[1] = { MPI_INT }; // size of pointer 
MPI_Type_create_struct(1, lenPhysObject, posPhysObject, typPhysObject, &dataTypePhysObject);
MPI_Type_commit(&dataTypePhysObject);
```

Here is a part of the code with MPI_Send/MPI_Recv

```cpp
PhysObject* obj = new PhysObject[1];
obj->obj_= new MyObject[1];
PhysObject* obj_2 = new PhysObject[1];
obj_2->obj_= new MyObject[1];
if(rank==1)
{
   obj->obj_->Speed = { 14, 0, 0 };
   MPI_Send(obj, 1, dataTypePhysObject, 0, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
if(rank==0)
{
   MPI_Recv(obj_2, 1, dataTypePhysObject, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   std::cout << obj_2->right->Speed.x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure but this might be relevant ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830608/mpi-send-derived-data-type-with-pointer-in-fortran-90/18830800#18830800

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark So if I have pointer object with pointers I must work send each pointer of this object in recieve thread, aren't I? Looks like it's not an optimized process.

Comment: Actually, it is optimized.  What you want requires serialization of the object which is a major extra functionality. The python interface does that, but that makes simple sends very slow. I suggest that you use `MPI_Pack` and `MPI_Unpack` to write your own serialization.

Comment: The answer to this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830608/mpi-send-derived-data-type-with-pointer-in-fortran-90/18830800#18830800) as @HighPerformanceMark said.